# Accessing a class object in PHP

Tags: php, xml, arrays

Does anyone has idea how to access HREF from the below object:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [title] => Preview
            [rel] => enclosure
            [type] => image/jpeg
            [href] => http://a1.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/008/Purple/94/ee/38/mzl.fupornmt.320x480-75.jpg
        )

)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`SimpleXMLElement::attributes`](http://lv.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php) method:

```
$attrs = $obj->attributes();
echo $attrs['href'];
```

Answer (score 3):

SimpleXML objects representing XML elements support array like access to the element attributes

```
(string)$simpleXMLElement['href']
```

The `(string)` cast is needed if you wish to compare the attribute with a string or pass it into a function that requires a string. Otherwise, PHP treats the attribute as an object. (That  applies if you use the `attributes()` method as well)

Answer (score 0):

Use simpleXML http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php

Answer (score 0):

I can't say "Vote Up", but as Anpher says, you just need to access the attribute:

```
$attrs = $obj->attribues(); // Gets you the "[@attributes]" array (which is a copy of the internal private property "attributes")

do_things_with($attrs['href']); // Accesses the element you want.
```